# All traffic is passed through OpenVPN although not requested

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, linux-networking, service

I have a bash script on a Ubuntu box which searches for the fastest openvpn server, connects, and binds one program to the tun0 interface. Unfortunately, all traffic is being passed through the VPN. Does anybody know what's going on?

The relevant line follows:

```
openvpn --daemon --config $cfile --auth-user-pass ipvanish.pass --status openvpn-status.log
```

There don't seem to be any entries in iptables when I enter `sudo iptables --list`.

The config files look like this:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote nyc-a04.ipvanish.com 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
persist-remote-ip
ca ca.ipvanish.com.crt
tls-remote nyc-a04.ipvanish.com
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 3
auth SHA256
cipher AES-256-CBC
keysize 256
tls-cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA
```

There is nothing in there that would direct everything through tun0, so maybe it's a new vagary of Ubuntu? I don't remember this happening in the past.

edit: Here is `ip r ls`:

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 172.20.24.1 dev tun0 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1  proto static 
128.0.0.0/1 via 172.20.24.1 dev tun0 
172.20.24.0/22 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.20.27.20 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.10  metric 1 
216.151.180.2 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth1
```

And ifconfig with some obfuscations:

```
[$] <> ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr *:*:*:*:*:*  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:fdbc0000-fdbe0000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr *:*:*:*:*:*  
          inet addr:192.168.0.10  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2604:*:*:*:*:*:*:*/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::223:54ff:fe07:6555/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:19923223 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35568399 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4692090933 (4.6 GB)  TX bytes:56325183667 (56.3 GB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:77741 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:77741 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:19058271 (19.0 MB)  TX bytes:19058271 (19.0 MB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:172.20.27.20  P-t-P:172.20.27.20  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15810638 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36553479 errors:0 dropped:146946 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:872811046 (872.8 MB)  TX bytes:49841453877 (49.8 GB)
```

Comment: What does the routing table look like? Check `ip r ls`

Comment: Please see my edit. It looks like the first line is responsible. Why is it there when I didn't add it? Also, what on earth is up with the last line I don't recognize that address, and it's not my isp address.

Comment: The OpenVPN server is perfectly capable of passing you routing instructions which your client will honour if you don't tell it not to.  I think it very likely that that's how that `tun0` route got into your routing tables.

Comment: How are you achieving your search for "fastest openvpn server" ?

Comment: There's a predictable naming scheme for the servers provided by my vpn, so I have a list of identifiers, which are converted to server addresses and pinged in a for loop. Whenever a faster ping is obtained, the server is selected. I can provide my code if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure split tunneling in the client by using something similar to the following in your .ovpn config file:

```
route-nopull
route 172.20.24.0 255.255.252.0 vpn_gateway
```

First line disables routing.
Second line adds the static route.

You might better address this on the server, but I am assuming that you are looking for a client side solution.

Comment: Is there a way to find out the route the server wants to push, then manually make the appropriate route? there is no way for me to know ahead of time the gateway address.

Comment: Maybe I need to grep the routing table for the line starting in 0.0.0.0, Get the IP address, add it as a route on a secondary routing table, add a rule for the tun0 interface going to that routing table, then delete the bad routes from the primary table (http://www.rjsystems.nl/en/2100-adv-routing.php). Or can I just grep the table, close the openvpn connection, and reopen it using the route config flag that you mentioned? This is all very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the server is configured to push route to the clients something like

```
push "redirect-gateway"
```

You make a client ignore all routes with the

```
route-nopull
```

directive in the client config file.

Comment: Perfect! I wanted to leave the config file untouched, since I have a script to automatically download it based on best ping time, so I added the switch to the input arguments:
`openvpn --daemon --config $cfile --route-nopull --auth-user-pass ipvanish.pass --status openvpn-status.log`

Comment: Actually, now it's not working at all. I need to add a static route, but it may be a different route depending on the server.